# Woocommerce redirection if no previous orders

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, order, wp-redirect

I am displaying **logged in** users their **order history** in the front end. Initially, when no order history, I used to get a blank page. However, after using this code

```
if ( !$customer_orders ) :
    echo esc_html("You haven't redeemed any offer");
endif;
```

I can display a message in the front-end saying "You haven't redeemed any offer"
**I want this page to redirect after 5 seconds on if this message is being displayed, otherwise users will get to see their order details.**

Can someone suggest something or extend this code? Check out the images for reference[Where redirection has to happen after 5 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXpyO.png)
[image: No redirect needed while there is order history]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a redirect after 5 seconds so for this you need to use javascript timeout. You can enqueue script as per standards. Adding this script inside the condition of no orders will do the task.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = "REDIRECT URL HERE";
    }, 5000);
});
```